# React native changing default page while in development

Tags: react-native

When in development it's easier/faster to develop if we can see the currently editing page as soon as the app is displayed in emulator. Is there an easy way to do this without changing the navigation paths manually?

Comment: Are you referring to [hot reloading](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading.html)?

Comment: Ah thanks. I was using live reload and it was always going to home page with each edit.